# A* and diagonal movement cost on 2D x,y grid

Tags: algorithm, search

I just coded up an A* algorithm for a 2D xy grid, and it works fine.  However, currently I treat moving diagonally the same as moving horizontally or vertically, when in actuality if we view it in Euclidean or Pythagorean terms, moving diagonally is roughly 40% further, so it should be roughly 40% more difficult to do it, if I want to view it that way for my model.

However, that's just it.  You are moving 40% further, yet it is also 40% more difficult to do it.  So if I decide to make this adjustment in my computations, it seems that everything should 'wash out' and I should get basically the same result anyway.  What I'm saying is, it seems that it should be fine to simply do nothing, instead of adding in a "move 40% further for 40% more difficulty" factor to the diagonal movement.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: A* is for finding the shortest path.  I don't see what "difficulty" has to do with it.  If you want to recognize that "up, up" is shorter than "up-left, up-right", then you'll have to recognize that diagonal moves are longer.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, call it "difficulty," call it "cost," call it whatever you want.  A* uses such a heuristic to figure out what the "shortest" (by whatever definition) path is.  In my case, each tile on the grid has a "difficulty" moving through that tile, whether that means it's paved road with almost no difficulty, or mountains/forest with a lot of difficulty.  Also, yeah, as I already said, I know moving diagonally is longer.  The question is whether this can be ignored, as it is also more difficult by the same ratio.

Answer (score 0):

if u sketch a rough 4x4 grid of nodes. try testing the various routes between a start and target node. u will see you are correct for the most part. however try the case where start is top left and target is top right. its 3 movements horizontally to get there, great. if diagonals are weighted the same though...u can create a boat-like shape (vertrightdown,horright,vertrightup) thats also 3 movements. u kno diagonals are indeed further to travel, so u kno there needs to be something in the algorithm to say the horizontal route is best. the order that neighbours r considered in could make this extra cost irrelevant tho. if the diagonal and horizontal are the same f values...it still has to choose between 1 or the other. so it depends how u select ur 'current-node' from the pool in ur open/frontier table when comparing f values. it really depends how u setup ur algorithm and what its usage is, u might not need to do anything at all.